# Challenges with ReadTheDocs

Tags: python, documentation, read-the-docs

I've been tasked with hosting our Python API docs for our customers to access.  ReadTheDocs.com was recommended by a colleague.  However, I've had some challenges with it:

1. The default approach is to give ReadTheDocs full access to our code repo, in which the documentation is just one sub-folder.  This is a non-starter and not possible.
2. So my next thought was to make a copy of the Docs folder into a separate repo and allow ReadTheDocs to access it.  The problem here is that documentation is auto-generated from our code so this approach leaves large swaths of the documentation incomplete.
3. ReadTheDocs doesn't appear to be able to host the built documentation website (ie. index.html et al) but perhaps I'm mistaken about this?

I'm seeking help from others who have encountered a similar Use Case. Did you find a way to get ReadTheDocs to work as you required or did you turn to another approach to host your documentation?  If the latter, what approach did you use?

We would require versioning (ie. 1.0.1, 1.0.2, etc.) and the export to a PDF file would be ideal.

Sincerely,

Robert W.

Comment: pay them for consulting work

Answer (score 3):

## A guide to ReadTheDocs

I've used ReadTheDocs for many of my own projects, and it really is a useful platform. As far as I've gathered from your question, you are trying to host HTML files from your repository (GitHub repo?). However, ReadTheDocs isn't made for hosting HTML - it actually builds ReStructuredText or Markdown files with [Sphinx](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/) (a documentation building system written in Python). Here is a typical scenario for setting up ReadTheDocs to host your documentation:

### Initialise files

1. Firstly, install Sphinx with `pip` - read [this](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/tutorial.html) for a guide on how to do so.
2. Next, go into the cloned repository on your computer and run `sphinx-quickstart` inside the `docs` folder (**must be an empty folder**).
3. The command should ask you some questions. Choose the following answers:

   - `Seperate source and build directories?`: **n**
   - `Project name`: a neat public-facing name for your project
   - `Author name(s)`: Name(s) of the developers who made the API
   - `Project release`: Current version of your API

   The rest can stay as default (press enter to take default option)
4. Commit the created files to your GitHub repo.
5. Sign up for a ReadTheDocs account and import your repository. By default, it will either build anything it sees in the root directory of your repo or in its `docs` folder (it will automatically determine which). If all is successful, you should be able to open your documentation page and see a demo page.

### Write and edit docs

You should now be able to edit your files to create your documentation. RTD's design is based off 'Themes', and most pages use https://github.com/rtfd/sphinx_rtd_theme. Theme repos usually give decent installation docs.

To edit your page, you need to edit `docs/index.rst`. RST stands for `ReStructuredText` and is similar to Markdown. You can find cheat sheets for it on the internet. Here is what the auto-generated file looks like:

```
.. Test documentation master file, created by
   sphinx-quickstart on Mon Mar 19 18:24:58 2018.
   You can adapt this file completely to your liking, but it should at least
   contain the root `toctree` directive.

Welcome to Test's documentation!
================================

.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 2
   :caption: Contents:


Indices and tables
==================

* :ref:`genindex`
* :ref:`modindex`
* :ref:`search`
```

You can remove the 'Indices and tables' section from the bottom - I'm not entirely sure of its purpose.

The `.. toctree::` is a universal menu - you only need to define it in `index.rst` and you can leave it out on other pages. To create a new page of documentation, create a new `*.rst` file. What you call it will correspond to the `.html` file that it is rendered into. For example, `parameters.rst` will be accessible through `http://mydocs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/parameters.html`. To add the `parameters.rst` page to your menu, it needs to look like this:

```
.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 2
   :captions: Contents:

   parameters
```

Essentially, you need to add the name of your `.rst` file (without the extension) to the `.. toctree` in your `index.rst` file (and nowhere else).

### Applying changes

To apply changes that you've made and publish them to your ReadTheDocs page, you simply need to commit your new `.rst` files to the `master` branch on GitHub, and RTD will automatically build and publish for you.

In case you haven't quite understood, RTD **does not take .html files**. You shouldn't commit *any* .html files to GitHub, just .rst files. The .rst files will be built by RTD and published.

### Versions

You can use Git tags to manage versions of your docs. For more detail, see http://docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/versions.html (official ReadTheDocs documentation).

Hope this is useful!

Comment: Pal, thank you for your response.  Forgive me for not being more clear.  Our docs ARE in the format that Sphinx requires.  But I cannot just copy to another repo the docs because of the links to docstrings in our code.  And we cannot provide ReadTheDocs with full access to our code.

Given these constraints, what would you advise us to do?

Comment: What do you mean by not being able to provide RTD with full access to your code? Is it a private Github repo? RTD is automated, so it won't read anything but your documentation source files.

Comment: To be clear, technically of course we can provide access to our repo but there is no way that management will permit this.  Fact is that our technology is not open source but is proprietary technology that we are hyper-careful about sharing.

It more & more sounds like RTD is the wrong fit for our needs.

Answer (score 0):

For API docs you can use [swagger](https://swagger.io) or [apidoc](http://apidocjs.com).

Answer (score 0):

If your project is on GitHub, your requirement can be met using [Github Actions](https://github.com/features/actions) along with a static site generator (SSG) of your choice supporting PDF generation.

In its simplest form, create a GH action to generate the static site folder of the branch/release, then push the folder to corresponding folder in the branch pointed to by GH pages, say *gh-pages*. One of the branches/releases should be pushed to root. [GitHub Pages Deploy Action](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/deploy-to-github-pages) can be helpful. Add a dropdown list of versions to your static website pointing to the matching folder.

Example:

- [GitHub action](https://github.com/bcgov/NotifyBC/blob/main/.github/workflows/ghPages.yml)
- [dropdown list implemented by Vue component](https://github.com/bcgov/NotifyBC/blob/main/docs/.vuepress/components/versions.vue)
- [rendered site powered by GH pages](https://bcgov.github.io/NotifyBC/)

Benefits over ReadTheDocs free plan:

- No ads
- Hosted entirely on GitHub, no 3rd party service nor authorization required.

Answer (score 0):

My approach was to write a script to copy the documentation source (rst) plus *only* the source code files needed to create the documentation (rather than the whole source tree). These were copied to a separate (private) GitHub repo that is used by Read the Docs to build the documents.

**In all cases, we *only* copy files to the GitHub repo that are part of the shipped product, so there should be no IP risk.**

- For C++ APIs (using `breathe`) this is just the public header files.
- For Python APIs it is either the Python sources or the built wheel files.

For the Python wheels, some of these need supporting object files (libs, etc). This meant using `git-lfs`, which is not officially supported by Read the Docs.

It was difficult to get it all to build initially (working out all the dependencies by trial and error), and it is still quite fragile, but it works.